# Create an On Change Event or Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am creating a report with a program in C# to output a Excel Spreadsheet Report

My customer wants to modify some data on the sheet and have it update automatically.

It is an inventory spreadsheet that has a report page with Departments and totals for each department.
On a second page it has an itemized List of every item in his store with quantity, item price, department, etc.

They want to be able to change the quantity/price per item and it be reflected in the right department total.

Itemized List of items:
[image: Itemized List of items]

Totals Reports by Department:
[image: Totals Reports by Department]

I have been looking thru all possibilities of this and I think a macro would be best for this.

Basically I need it to be:

an On change Event If any cell in Column F or B changes It will take The cell from column G that corresponds to that change and add it to the Department on page 1 which Department is in cell C

So

```
 if (B2 or F2) Changes
 {
    Match B3 on page 2 to department in A column of page 1 then add total to B column

    ADD G2 (page 2) to B13 (page 1) which is Grocery_02 on page 1 but it may not always be B13

 }
```

Comment: why not use formula's to calculate the Total?

Comment: Be aware that the following does not exist: `if (B2 or F2) Changes then launch OnChange Event`, the only possibility is something like `Sub OnChange (target sender){ if sender is (B2 or F2) then ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use formulas for sure. it is the easiest implementation and unless the workbook is set to have manual calculation then it will always update any time a referenced cell changes.

I would use a simple =(Qty * Retail) formula for the "Total_Retail" column for the itemized listing, and a SUMIF function for the department totals.

[image]
[image]
[image]